# pip3 reinstall on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, python3, pip

Recently I have faced with the issue that on Ubuntu 18.04 **pip3** does not work properly:

```
:~$ pip3 install jinja2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/redra/.local/bin/pip3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

Then I have tried to reinstall pip3, seems like it is due to it and faced with another issue:

```
:~$ sudo -H python3 get-pip.py
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting pip
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
```

I guess it is stucking ... I cannot install openssl due to bad pip3 and cannot install a new pip3 due to openssl ... Seems like it is cycle (

Any suggestion ? Has anybody faced with the same issue ?

Comment: Did you try reinstalling python as a whole? `sudo apt-get purge python3 && sudo apt-get install python3`

Comment: @AmithKK I have installed Python 3.7 from sources

Comment: Any reason you've specifically built it from source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably because the required `openssl` binaries were not present when you compiled python, to fix this

- download openssl (tar.gz shall do the trick) from: https://www.openssl.org/source/
- untar SSL source in folder
- Goto the folder and run the following to make openssl

  `./configure && make && sudo make install`

Finally - redo the Python compilation (configure, make, make install), observe that ssl library now compiles into Python as it appears in standard place where Python compiling procedure is looking for.